# How to avoid circular dependencies when using pydantic v2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, pydantic-v2

I have a `Snapshot` class in one file with instance method `view` which returns a `View` class defined in another file. But also instance of `View` needs to be constructed with `Snapshot` instance.

Requirements:

- have these 2 classes in separate files
- use pydantic-v2 types and checks correctly everywhere

I have come up with the solution below, but using `"get_snapshot_class()"` and `TYPE_CHEKCING` seems a bit like a hack. Is there a better solution?

```
# snapshot.py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from pydantic import BaseModel

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from .view import View


class Snapshot(BaseModel):
    position: str

    def view(self, context: str) -> "View":
        # Delay import to avoid circular import
        from .view import View

        return View(snapshot=self, context=context)
```

```
# view.py
from pydantic import BaseModel


def get_snapshot_class():
    from qcs.snapshot import Snapshot

    return Snapshot


class View(BaseModel):
    snapshot: "get_snapshot_class()"
    context: str
```

Comment: you could just put them in the same module, otherwise, you will need to do something like this. why exactly is this a requirement?

Comment: you should only have to delay the import in one of these, though

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks. why is it requirement? in the real code I have more interdependent classes like this with  hundreds LOC, so I prefer to have my code more modular.